# MAC OS Mounting and booting from Ramdisk when starting up

Tags: mac, bootloader, ramdisk

Is it possible to do the following automatic actions each time OSX starting up?

Press Power Button

1. Boot Mac
2. Create Ramdisk
3. Load OSX to Ramdisk
4. Boot from Ramdisk

   Then I should be able to use normally OSX from Ramdisk until turn off

Additional informations:

**a)** I want to use a USB FlashDrive with the OSX version which will be loaded to ramdisk, and the ramdisk boot ONLY will happens if this USB Flashdrive is plugged.

**b)** I don't need mirror changes to SSD or HD drive, what is lost will be lost.

**c)** The OSX that will be loaded into ramdisk will be as light as possible, with a large portion of the features disabled or uninstalled. Only with audio and web functionality would it be possible to have a bootable OS of 4-8GB?

**d)** In the machine which will be tested, I have only 16GB ram (Mac Mini late 2012)

I will be very grateful if all is possible with a script or some kind like that.

Thanks!

Comment: you cant do this.  and why do you want to do this?

Comment: For high end audio listening. There is a well-documented consensus in audiophile forums that direct audio playback in ram memory is more noise-free for sensitive equipment because of low latency and other details. Playing music straight in Ram with linux has shown excellent results, I want to test and compare if OS X also achieves similar results.

Comment: where do you think the audio file you are playing is being read from?  Its read off of disk into RAM and then being played.  Dont believe everything you read on "audiophile" forums.

Comment: I'd love to see a link to some of this "well-documented consensus".. I haven't had a good laugh in ages. Some of the stuff audiophiles come up with is just "voodoo magic", like tying knots in your cables to 'balance the interference'. [btw, I'm a professional sound engineer, so if there is anything in what they're saying, I'd like to know.]

Comment: I am not a expert, but running OS from Ram is something to do with low latency.

https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30323/when-does-audio-latency-matter-and-not-matter

I would be very grateful if you guys can help me! Of course I will let you know if its a new audiophile myth. lol

Comment: I found this forum when googling about running OS from Ram, and found a Tetsujin script for Ramdisk + Raid 1 

https://superuser.com/questions/1048114/ramdisk-ssd-raid-1-boot-osx?rq=1

Comment: Latency does not affect audio quality - otherwise how do you think we record & playback 120 tracks of audio & associated effects plugins without issue, in a pro environment. Latency is compensated. Anything else is pure snake oil. BTW, your links... 1st is irrelevant to this & 2nd *I wrote the answer*, which uses Applescript & needs the OS to be loaded first ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Hi Tetsujin, let me disagree with you.:) Latency is of utmost importance for audio playback. Even if it's compensated, we're talking about hi-fi reproduction, something an audio engineer would worry about. There are many articles that talk about the importance of low latency that are not audiophiles. And maybe a apple script is what I'm looking for! What I need is the OSX running only in the ramdisk.
https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26036/what-is-latency-in-a-digital-recording-studio  https://www.presonus.com/learn/technical-articles/Digital-Audio-Latency-Explained

Comment: I'm sorry, but again you are completely misunderstanding how latency works & how [& why & when] it is compensated for. Aside from that, it's impossible to do what you are attempting to do. Even if you could achieve it, it wouldn't improve anything at all.

Comment: No. See the first comment. Also - **it would not gain you anything at all.** You are wasting your time & looking in the wrong direction. You still didn't post links to this "well-documented consensus" so we could at least see if there is even a kernel of truth in it, or whether it's the usual audiophile 'fooling yourself' stuff that they just seem to lap up.

Comment: @Tetsujin 
http://www.aviom.com/library/Application-Notes/63_Managing-Jitter-Wander-and-Latency-in-Digital-Audio-Networks.pdf

Comment: Again, you are conflating information - that discusses network jitter; orders of magnitude higher than those inside any single system & synchronisation issues over a network. This again has nothing to do with what you think you are trying to achieve... which is not possible & will not gain you anything.

Comment: Time-alignment for phase coherence at playback is done by the audio DACs.. nothing that occurs before that is of any importance, except to be able to feed the DACs quickly enough, which is truly trivial for any modern computer - it can time-align hundreds of streams to present to the DACs as coherent stereo or multichannel audio with time to spare.

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand. Then, is it possible a script which do following things: in all startup 1) create a ram disk (4GB) 2)copy the application in the SSD, called ROON to ramdisk 3) run Roon direct from ram 4 )all changings I do in Roon in the Ram mode will be mirrored to the Roon in the SSD.

Comment: Sure it is - but it will gain you absolutely nothing at all. What you want is a myth, a dream, magicked up by 'audiophiles' who have not the first clue how any of this works.